# Detect if golang method is internal?

Tags: go, reflection

I'm writing a function that iterates over the methods on a given struct and binds the methods to handlers. I would like to skip over internal methods if possible. I'm not sure if this is possible to do so explicitly - I reviewed the documentation for the reflect package and I didn't see a means to detect if a given Value is an internal method. I know I can get the method's name, and then check if it starts with a lowercase character but I'm not sure if there's a kosher way to accomplish this. It's also possible that the internal / public boundary really only exists at compile time anyways, so there really isn't even a way of knowing this beyond the method's name. In either case I'd like to know for sure. Thanks!

Comment: just fyi, the correct terminology is exported / unexported. Not a huge deal, but it helps when searching.

Comment: @captncraig thanks, I'm relatively new to go. I mostly write in swift which has open / public / internal (default) / fileprivate / private access control levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflect package will not give you unexported methods via `Type.Method`. Pretty much, if you can see it via reflect, it is already exported.

See https://play.golang.org/p/61qQYO38P0

Comment: Awesome! I can't accept your answer for 10 minutes but I will when I can.